# How to compile a Netbeans project using javac

Tags: java, netbeans, javac

I'm writing a project in netbeans, but I need it to be compiled with javac, because it is needed to be built and executed through CLI. How can I do that? I've seen a lot of project specific answers, but none suits my problem. I've read javac's man, and setted the classpath properly: `javac -cp .. MyMain.java`, conssidering that my project have the following structure:

```
src
 |_mainPackage
           |_package2
           |_package3
           |_MyMain.java
```

and I'm using the dot format in my imports like this:

```
import package1.class1
import package2.class2

public class MyMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Stuff with classes in package1
            .
            .
            .
    //Stuff with classes in package2
            .
            .
            .
  }
}
```

I can't use ant, because it is meant to be compiled using javac in the CLI, since it is a college project and have some restrictions imposed by the professors.

**EDIT:**
I actually got to compile my sources using javac with the command `usr@host: mainPackage $ javac -cp .. MyMain.java`, since my imports use dot separation format, and the "root package" is located in 'mainPackage' folder; but when i'm going to run the project, i have this output:

```
usr@host: mainPackage $ java VideoRent 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyMain (wrong name: mymain/MyMain)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: MyMain.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: Just the same way as you compile multiple classes. What exactly is the problem you're having? Don't you know how to `cd` up to the folder representing the package root or something? Or don't you know how to compile multiple classes altogether? Are you able to compile a single class?

Comment: It looks like you are setting your CLASSPATH to one directory up from your current directory "javac -cp .. MyMain.java" which could be causing your problem.

Comment: @BalusC: well, I have a long time since I last programmed in java, but I remember that I didnt used packages at all. I put all my classes under the same folder, and executed `javac MainClas.java` to compile, and then `java MainClass` to run; and it handled every dependency I needed. Actually, using the command above, i made it to compile my class, but then i'm getting a weird error. check my edit.

Comment: You don't have compile problems at all. You have execution problems. The exception is telling that you executed the class as `java MyMain` while the class itself is in the `mymain` package and should thus be executed as `java mymain.MyMain`. But this doesn't correspond with the file structure and code examples you've given as far. This means that you've obfuscated/oversimplified the code too much without realizing what you were doing. In the future please rename package/classnames for in the question with extreme care, or at least setup a playground project.

Comment: @BalusC: yes! when i first posted the question, i couldn't even compile, but by the time i edited, i could compile but not execute. That's the answer! using dot notation on java call. Just like you pointed, i now realize i was wrong in package structure... anyways, thank you very much for your efforts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a clean temporary directory, try this sequence of commands. Then inspect and understand the directory layout, package declarations, and various path settings like `-d bin`, `-s src`, and `-cp bin`:

```
mkdir -p src/mainPackage
echo "package mainPackage; public class MyMain { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(\"Hello world\"); }}" > src/mainPackage/MyMain.java
mkdir bin
javac -d bin -s src src/mainPackage/MyMain.java 
java -cp bin mainPackage.MyMain
```

Comment: https://github.com/SpotterRF/json-examples/tree/master/java/jackson has a good example in the Makefile

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
javac.exe -d class -s src src/myproject/mainpackage/*.java 
      src/myproject/mainpackage/package2/*.java 
        src/myproject/mainpackage/package3/*.java
```

Could try this also (Windows)

`for /r %%a in (*.java) do ( javac "%%a" )`

Comment: thank you very much!, but im using linux, and my project will be executed on linux Debian. Ive read javac's man, and says the -d option is the directory where .class files are going to be stored, so i cant pass a class to -d option. Any ideas on linux?

Comment: -d class means to put the .class files in folder called class ^^